# Destructuring two objects

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Why doesn't this destructuring work? Can someone help me? I'm using gatsby and graphql.

```js
 // desctructure the “acf” field
  const { wordpressAcfRedessociais: { acf }, wordpressPage: {acf2} } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  
  query {
    wordpressAcfRedessociais {
      acf {
        facebook
      
      }
    }
    wordpressPage(wordpress_id: { eq: 47 }) {
      acf {
        citat_1_text
       
      }
    }
  }
`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because there is nothing called `acf2` within `wordpressPage`. You would have to provide an alias for it since you can't have 2 consts/variables with same name.

> wordpressPage: { acf: acf2 }

```
const { wordpressAcfRedessociais: { acf }, wordpressPage: { acf: acf2 } } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  
  query {
    wordpressAcfRedessociais {
      acf {
        facebook
      
      }
    }
    wordpressPage(wordpress_id: { eq: 47 }) {
      acf {
        citat_1_text
       
      }
    }
  }
`)
```